# When does accusation happen?

Tags: accuser

An accuser needs to show a baker double-baked the same block. That means an accuser needs to accuse after the baked block in question has already been baked, correct?

So an accuser must accuse at the earliest in the following block, right?. Can an accuser, in theory, accuse of a double bake within the deposit holding period, which would be several cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the answers in the : [Tezos docs (the part on proof-of-stake)](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#accusations)

Basically, an accuser needs to show that a baker baked **two blocks at the same level**.

The accuser emits an accusation operation with the double-baking evidence (namely, the headers of the two blocks). If this accusation operation is included in a block within the cycle of the incident and 5 cycles in the future, then the accusation is taken into account: it has as an effect the loss of the offending baker's deposit and rewards.